# Ember routes specifying a different root url

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, routes, ember-data

I've an application running on my wamp server.  The directory structure looks like this
Wamp/www/applicationliveshere   However I've an ember application within the same directory and it's structure looks like this   Wamp/www/emberApp/applicationliveshere
I've set up my php project using REST so that I can access the my data using eg.  Get http:localhost/emberApp/videos     will return all the videos in the database as Json to the client.  However my problem is in Ember I'm unsure how to set up my routes to use localhost/emberApp/videos.  Currently each time I load the page the controller is using localhost/videos and returning with the a 404 Not found.   I am using 'ember-data.js' to handle my models. And I have created a Store as follows

```
Videos.Store = DS.Store.extend({ revision: 12, url: "http://localhost/emberApp/"})
```

My Videos route is defined like this

```
Videos.VideosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ model: function(){
return Videos.Video.find();
}
});
```

I also have the path set as follows

```
Videos.Router.map(function({
this.resource('videos', {path: '/'});
});
```

So to clarify I want all my routes to begin with `http://localhost/emberApp/.....`
But at the moment I have `http://localhost/....`

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With ember RC.6 you can use the latest ember data, (0.13) which won't need `revision: 12` defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the behavior you need you should also define the `namespace` on the adapter additionally to the `url` in the store.

For example:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'emberApp'
});

Videos.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12, 
  url: "http://localhost/",
  adapter: App.Adapter
});
```

This will result in `http://localhost/emberApp/` as your base url.
Have also a look [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/) for info on that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Have implemented it but unfortunately the debugger still shows that it is looking for http://localhost/videos without emberApp in the address.  I must be missing something else.  Any ideas where I can look for further documentation on this subject?

Comment: @LindaKeating, just edited my answer, please have a look now, this should work

Comment: Worked a treat.  Thanks so much.  Exactly what I was looking for.